# I can't create an outlet in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am new to Xcode and I try to create an outlet of an MKMapView, I tried to control-drag the path from the map to the ViewController.swift, but it didn't work. Whats the reason for that and do I have to manually add them every time?

Comment: Does your ViewController in the Storyboard have the same backing class as your ViewController.swift?

Comment: did you set the class name in the storyboard? give us some more details about what you did and what you observe

Comment: Well, I got the following setup:

Comment: http://prnt.sc/awolbt but I tried to change the class of the View Controllers to "UIViewController" but I can't. Sorry, I'm new to Xcode and Swift

Comment: Please open the Identity Inspector in your Xcode and select the viewController in Storyboard, then take another screenshot

Comment: Got it now, but maybe somebody could help me with another problem. Feel free to write me, because I reached the question limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into your storyboard file and select the view controller with the above mentioned MKMapView. Click the identity inspector and in "Custom Class" make "Class" equal to "ViewController".

Comment: Got it now, can I maybe contact you because I got another problem and don't really know how to solve it. Would be great :)

Comment: Thank you, I'll mail you in some minutes.